# AMP Validation error The attribute 'value' may not appear in tag 'meta'

Tags: wordpress, twitter, amp-html

Amp validator give me an error in most of the post of my site since a week ago.
Its related with Twitter Targs

```
 <pre><meta name="twitter:label2" value="Tiempo de lectura"> <meta name="twitter:data2" value="1 minuto"> </pre>
```

I use wordpress, yoast and amp plugin to serve my amp pages version.

Here´s the plugin configuration

[Plugin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GErY0.png)

Comment: There are few fixes in the recent Yoast version 15.2.1
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/#developers

Fixes a bug where AMP and W3C validation would break because Twitter meta tags would contain ‘value’ attributes instead of ‘content’ attributes.

Can you please update the Yoast SEO plugin to the latest version and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fix in the recent Yoast SEO plugin version [15.2.1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/#developers)

Changelog

*Fixes a bug where AMP and W3C validation would break because Twitter meta tags would contain ‘value’ attributes instead of ‘content’ attributes.*

Can you please update the Yoast SEO plugin to the latest version, this should fix your issue.